# HtmlAgilityPack upload file

Tags: c#, post, file-upload, upload, html-agility-pack

I'm getting stuck in HtmlAgilityPack, it work fine when posting plain text to server. But currently I need to use it to upload an image, using multipart/form-data format and the Content-Type: image/jpeg. 
I already searched this problem on google over 2 days but no result at all. I'm very grateful if you can give me any idea to solve this problem.

Or could you please suggest me use another library which can done this task?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you show how you upload plain text to server?

Comment: The HAP is an HTML parser - how exactly are you using it to upload _anything_?

Comment: This is an example http://dbanck.de/2010/01/09/post-data-with-net-html-agility-pack/

Comment: Never mind, already solved my problem, this is the best example:
http://technet.rapaport.com/Info/LotUpload/SampleCode/Full_Example.aspx